# Class for newtype

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass

I have a newtype

```
newtype ScopedTable sym = ScopedTable { tab_stack :: [ Map String sym ] }
```

because I want to have a symbol-table-like structure for different *symbol* types.

On my first try, I wrote a class for using the ScopedTable in a generic manner when inside a monad, in the class we just get a Lens to focus on the `ScopedTable`:

```
class STScopedTable st where
        st_table :: Lens' st (ScopedTable sym)
```

Notice the `Lens'` focuses on `ScopedTable sym`, and this is `sym` the only place that it appears in the `class`.

Now when instantiating the class

```
data OpPState = OpPState { _opp_table :: ScopedTable Operator }
makeLenses ''OpPState

instance STScopedTable OpPState where
        st_table = opp_table
```

there's a *type-checking* error:

```
src/Language/Angler/MixfixParser.hs:74:20:
    Couldn't match type ‘sym’ with ‘Operator’
      ‘sym’ is a rigid type variable bound by
            the type signature for
              st_table :: Functor f =>
                          (ScopedTable sym -> f (ScopedTable sym)) -> OpPState -> f OpPState
            at src/Language/Angler/MixfixParser.hs:74:9
    Expected type: (ScopedTable sym -> f (ScopedTable sym))
                   -> OpPState -> f OpPState
      Actual type: (ScopedTable Operator -> f (ScopedTable Operator))
                   -> OpPState -> f OpPState
    Relevant bindings include
      st_table :: (ScopedTable sym -> f (ScopedTable sym))
                  -> OpPState -> f OpPState
        (bound at src/Language/Angler/MixfixParser.hs:74:9)
    In the expression: opp_table
    In an equation for ‘st_table’: st_table = opp_table
```

---

So I tried the `MultiParamTypeClasses` pragma, and now the sym would have to be passed to the class:

```
class STScopedTable st sym where
        st_table :: Lens' st (ScopedTable sym)
```

But now it won't allow me to use the class constraint properly:

```
enterSc :: (STScopedTable s sym, MonadState s m) => m ()
enterSc = use st_table >>= assign st_table . enterScope
```

It gives me the error:

```
src/Language/Angler/Monad.hs:79:12:
    Could not deduce (STScopedTable s sym0)
    from the context (STScopedTable s sym, MonadState s m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 enterSc :: (STScopedTable s sym, MonadState s m) => m ()
      at src/Language/Angler/Monad.hs:79:12-56
    The type variable ‘sym0’ is ambiguous
    In the ambiguity check for the type signature for ‘enterSc’:
      enterSc :: forall (m :: * -> *) s sym.
                 (STScopedTable s sym, MonadState s m) =>
                 m ()
    To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
    In the type signature for ‘enterSc’:
      enterSc :: (STScopedTable s sym, MonadState s m) => m ()
```

I enabled `AllowAmbiguousTypes` pragma and now I get:

```
src/Language/Angler/Monad.hs:81:15:
    Could not deduce (STScopedTable s sym0)
      arising from a use of ‘st_table’
    from the context (STScopedTable s sym, MonadState s m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 enterSc :: (STScopedTable s sym, MonadState s m) => m ()
      at src/Language/Angler/Monad.hs:80:12-56
    The type variable ‘sym0’ is ambiguous
    In the first argument of ‘use’, namely ‘st_table’
    In the first argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘use st_table’
    In the expression: use st_table >>= assign st_table . enterScope
```

---

I could write `enterSc` for each monad I use with this class, but that would defeat the purpose of doing the generalisation.

If someone could give me an idea on how to fix the first try, I would prefer that, since I always prefer to use less pragmas. But if you elaborate on the second try, I would appreciate it too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GHC doesn't know what type to pick for `sym` in `enterSc` since it is only used in the constraint and nowhere else.

You can fix this with a functional dependency:

```
class STScopedTable st sym | st -> sym where
        st_table :: Lens' st (ScopedTable sym)
```

This tells GHC that the `sym` type is uniquely determined by the `st` type in all the instances of `STScopedTable`. Since `MonadState` has a functional dependency saying that `s` is uniquely determined by `m` we also know (due to transitivity) that `sym` is uniquely determined by `m` (the monad we eventually end up working in).

Avoiding pragmas isn't necessarily a good thing. I don't think it is possible to disambiguate your first version without enabling any pragmas. It's a good idea to avoid certain pragmas like `IncoherentInstances` when possible, but I wouldn't suggest making a general rule of avoiding pragmas.

Comment: The *functional dependency* was enough for the `enterSc` function, I didn't need the `Proxy`, thank you!

Comment: @chamini2 Ah cool. I was just now wondering if that was the case. The reason it works is that `MonadState` has a fundep saying that `s` is uniquely determined by `m` and the fundep we added says that `sym` is uniquely determined by `s`. So, transitively, `sym` is uniquely determined by `m` (the monad that we eventually end up working in).

Comment: Ow, that's pretty awesome, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: In my limited experience, `AllowAmbiguousTypes` can sometimes help produce a better error message, but once the problem is solved it can generally be disabled. Aside from avoiding `IncoherentInstances` like the plague, you should also shun `ImpredicativeTypes`, which basically doesn't work.